Django Admin Validate across normal fields and inlines
I have a model like with two ManyToMany relations and an corresponding admin class:

The first relation included in "filter_horizontal"
The second relation is an inline that is included in "inlines"

Everything works fine as long as I don't need to add custom validation.
When trying to implement a "check" method on the Model itself, the data for the inline model admin is not included.
But I need access to the data from both relations at the same time.
How can this be done?
